# Recursive CTE to assign "family" id to all nodes of the tree

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have data that looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE IDs(
    ParentId varchar(255),
    OrderId varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO IDs
VALUES
( '2', '1'),
( '3', '1'),
( '4', '1'),
( '5', '1'),
( '1', '6'),
( '6', '7'),
( '7', '8'),
( '7', '9'),

( '10', '11'),
( '11', '12'),
( '12', '13'),
( '14', '15'),
( '15', '16'),
( '16', '17'),
( '18', '19'),
( '19', '20'),

( '20', '21'),
( '17', '21'),
( '13', '21'),
( '21', '1')


;
```

which represents orders that reference other orders.
there are multiple trees in the table where some nodes have multiple parents and some have multiple children. I have written a recursive CTE query here that shows their treepath

```
WITH
  ctefamily (ParentId ,OrderId, LEVEL, treepath)
  AS
  (

  --anchor table begins , selects ParentId without a corresponding OrderID

    SELECT ParentId , OrderId, 1 AS LEVEL, CAST(ParentId + '->' + OrderId AS VARCHAR(1024)) AS treepath

    FROM IDs id 

    --compare ParentId to Order Id's where parent id doesn't have an order ID
     WHERE not exists (
       select 1   
       from IDs id2
       where id.ParentId = id2.OrderId
       )


    UNION ALL

    SELECT id.ParentId , id.OrderId, LEVEL + 1 as LEVEL,
    CAST(r.treepath + '->' + CAST(id.OrderId AS VARCHAR(1024)) AS VARCHAR(1024)) AS treepath

    --recursive member keeping track of how many layers deep an order number has been referenced
    FROM
    --join to anchored table recursivly where ParentId is equal to an OrderID in anchor table, and so on...
    Ids id
      INNER JOIN ctefamily r
        ON id.ParentId = r.OrderId     
  )
SELECT distinct
  *
FROM ctefamily
order by LEVEL
```

which gives the result

```
ParentID  OrderID LEVEL treepath
2   1   1   2->1
21  1   4   18->19->20->21->1
21  1   5   10->11->12->13->21->1
21  1   5   14->15->16->17->21->1
3   1   1   3->1
4   1   1   4->1
5   1   1   5->1
10  11  1   10->11
11  12  2   10->11->12
12  13  3   10->11->12->13
14  15  1   14->15
15  16  2   14->15->16
16  17  3   14->15->16->17
18  19  1   18->19
19  20  2   18->19->20
13  21  4   10->11->12->13->21
17  21  4   14->15->16->17->21
20  21  3   18->19->20->21
1   6   2   2->1->6
1   6   2   3->1->6
1   6   2   4->1->6
1   6   2   5->1->6
1   6   5   18->19->20->21->1->6
1   6   6   10->11->12->13->21->1->6
1   6   6   14->15->16->17->21->1->6
6   7   3   2->1->6->7
6   7   3   3->1->6->7
6   7   3   4->1->6->7
6   7   3   5->1->6->7
6   7   6   18->19->20->21->1->6->7
6   7   7   10->11->12->13->21->1->6->7
6   7   7   14->15->16->17->21->1->6->7
7   8   4   2->1->6->7->8
7   8   4   3->1->6->7->8
7   8   4   4->1->6->7->8
7   8   4   5->1->6->7->8
7   8   7   18->19->20->21->1->6->7->8
7   8   8   10->11->12->13->21->1->6->7->8
7   8   8   14->15->16->17->21->1->6->7->8
7   9   4   2->1->6->7->9
7   9   4   3->1->6->7->9
7   9   4   4->1->6->7->9
7   9   4   5->1->6->7->9
7   9   7   18->19->20->21->1->6->7->9
7   9   8   10->11->12->13->21->1->6->7->9
7   9   8   14->15->16->17->21->1->6->7->9
```

This isn't really what I want. Id like for every ID that is referenced or being referenced to be assigned a family Id. so a fifth column would be added "familyid" and in this example every OrderID value in this table would reference the same family, there could also be multiple hierarchies like this in the same table, which I haven't added because I was just focusing on getting it right for one hierarchy for simplicity.

I've tried this with cursors as well and I get stuck when a parent references multiple children.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you want [graph component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory))

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure at your desire results as you didn't include a desired result set, but I think I understand the goal is to group orders into families. Assuming families must share a common ancestor, I was able to group them by storing the highest ancestor aka root id

See code below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ID
CREATE TABLE #ID(
    ParentID int
    ,ID int
)
INSERT INTO #ID
VALUES
 ( 2, 1)
,( 3, 1)
,( 4, 1)
,( 5, 1)
,( 1, 6)
,( 6, 7)
,( 7, 8)
,( 7, 9)
,(10,11)
,(11,12)
,(12,13)
,(14,15)
,(15,16)
,(16,17)
,(18,19)
,(19,20)
,(20,21)
,(17,21)
,(13,21)
,(21, 1)

;WITH cte_Family As (
    SELECT 
        A.Id
        ,A.ParentId
        ,LevelNum = 1
        ,RootID = A.ParentID
        ,TreePath = Cast(Concat(ParentId,'->',ID) as Varchar(4000))
    FROM #ID AS A /*No ancestors*/
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM #ID AS dta
        WHERE A.ParentId = dta.ID
    )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        B.ID
        ,B.ParentId
        ,A.LevelNum + 1
        ,A.RootID
        ,Cast(Concat(A.treepath,'->',B.ID) AS Varchar(4000))
    FROM cte_Family AS A /*Parent*/
    INNER JOIN #ID AS B /*Child*/
        ON B.ParentID = A.ID   
  )
SELECT *
    /*Use either RootID as the "FamilyId" or can use Rank to create a surrogate key*/
    ,SurrogateFamilyID = Dense_Rank() Over (Order by RootID)
FROM cte_Family
ORDER BY RootID,LevelNum,ID
```